# How to deploy an Angular app to Evennode?

Tags: angular, deployment, evennode

I would like to know how to deploy an Application using Angular to EvenNode.

I got stuck after the git deploy part.

Websites used:
Angular: https://angular.io/quick-start
Evennode: https://www.evennode.com/docs/git-deployment

I think that the trick could be on the: "npm install" part.

Thanks for any help!